# azureml No module named 'xgboost'

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I'm running a python notebook in Azure ML and created an Auto ML experiment and attempting deploy a mode using Python script. Model deploys successfully and I can see the endpoints, however, when posting to the end point I'm getting the 'No module named 'xgboost' as output.

Here is my YAML for conda, where I'm including py-xgboost and xgboost as well.

What am I missing?

name: project_environment
dependencies:

- python=3.6.2
- pip:

  - inference-schema
  - azureml-defaults
  - azureml-explain-model
  - numpy>=1.16.0,<1.17.0
  - pandas>=0.21.0,<=0.23.4
  - scikit-learn>=0.19.0,<=0.20.3
  - py-xgboost
  - fbprophet==0.5
  - holidays==0.9.11
  - psutil>=5.2.2,<6.0.0
  - xgboost
  - azureml-sdk[notebooks,automl]
    channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by making sure the pip and the conda packages are separated properly. See the indententation at numpy.

Additionally, adding in azureml-defaults will bring in the azureml related packages.

name: project_environment
dependencies:

- python=3.6.2
- pip:

  - azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.11.0.post1
  - inference-schema
  - azureml-explain-model==1.11.0
  - azureml-defaults==1.11.0
- numpy>=1.16.0,<1.17.0
- pandas>=0.21.0,<=0.23.4
- scikit-learn>=0.19.0,<=0.20.3
- py-xgboost<=0.90
- fbprophet==0.5
- holidays==0.9.11
- psutil>=5.2.2,<6.0.0
  channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge